# How to create a new variable from a runtime variable in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, yaml, pipeline

```
- job: working_on_compute
  timeoutInMinutes: 180
  dependsOn: gettoken1
  variables:
    SCHEMA_SUFFIX: $[env.config.outputs['checkconfigtask.startdate'] ]
    ${{ if eq(length(variables['SCHEMA_SUFFIX']), 0) }}:
    DB_SCHEMA: ""
    ${{ elseif ne(length(variables['SCHEMA_SUFFIX']), 0) }}:
    DB_SCHEMA: "_$(SCHEMA_SUFFIX)"
```

Here `SCHEMA_SUFFIX` is a runtime variable. I need to make a dynamic calculation and find the `DB_SCHEMA` variable . How to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

As the variable `SCHEMA_SUFFIX` is a runtime variable we couldn't make any conditions with that variable. So I moved the condition check to the `env` part of the bash script and made the conditional statement there and set the variable to a new key like the below in a bash.
[image]

```
 - job: working_on_compute
   timeoutInMinutes: 180
   dependsOn: gettoken1
   variables:
    SCHEMA_SUFFIX: $[env.config.outputs['checkconfigtask.startdate'] ]
    DB_SCHEMA: $[env.config.outputs['checkconfigtask.startdate'] ]
```